# How to escape a single quote directly in lightning markup?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

This has been answered for visualforce, apex, html etc, but couldn't find anything for within a lightning markup.

```
<aura:attribute name="mode" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedOption" type="String" default="{!if(v.mode == 'overlay', 'Closed', 'Open')}"/>
```

Now I need something like below so I could use pass it directly to a SOQL behind the scene:

```
<aura:attribute name="staticFilterCondition" type="String" default="{!'Status__c = \'' + v.selectedOption + '\''"/>
```

As you can see, the default value of `staticFilterCondition` attribute must be `Status__c = 'Open'` or `Status__c = 'Closed'` based on `selectedOption`. How to? I know this can be done via `init`, but wondering if there is a way to directly handle this in the markup?

I looked at the [expression functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) and tried below but no luck. Returns `Status__c = Open`

```
<aura:attribute name="staticFilterConditionPart1" type="String" default="Status__c = "/>
<aura:attribute name="staticFilterConditionPart2" type="String" default="'"/>
<aura:attribute name="staticFilterConditionPart3" type="String" default="{!concat(concat(v.staticFilterConditionPart1, staticFilterConditionPart2), v.selectedOption)}"/>
<aura:attribute name="staticFilterConditionPart4" type="String" default="'"/>
<aura:attribute name="staticFilterCondition" type="String" default="{!concat(v.staticFilterConditionPart3, staticFilterConditionPart4)}"/>
```

Comment: Even if it were possible, please put logic inside your `doInit` as it's pretty anti-pattern to place so much logic inside an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to "escape the escapes", meaning it should look more like:

```
<aura:attribute name="staticFilterCondition" 
                type="String" 
                default="{!'Status__c = \\\'' + v.selectedOption + '\\\''}"/>
```

However, I don't think this will work, since the order of default initialization isn't specified, so there's no way to guarantee that v.selectedOption will be set before init (aura:valueInit) is fired. I would do so in the init function.